# text not being added to raster plot

Tags: r, r-raster

I am plotting a raster like this:

```
library(raster)

raster = raster("C:\\Pathway\\raster.tif")

plot(raster)
text(0.4, 0.8, "text")
```

but my text isn't added. When I use a pre-loaded raster in the `raster` package it works.  For instance:

```
plot(raster(volcano))
text(0.4, 0.8, "text")
```

my text gets added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the point `c(0.4, 0.8)` is included(*) in the extent of your raster? When you first plot the raster, this sets the limits of the plot region, and if the coordinates of your text do not belong to them, it won't appear...

(*) or not too far away

```
library(raster)

r = raster(volcano)

par(mfrow=c(3,1))

plot(r)
text(0.4, 0.8, "text")

extent(r) = c(1,2,1,2) #Change the extent --> c(0.4,0.8) is quite far away
plot(r)
text(0.4, 0.8, "text") # does NOT appear...

plot(r)
text(1.4, 1.8, "text") # Back in the plot region --> does indeed appear
text(0.8, 1.5, "Close enough") # Does also appear...
```

[image]